# Extract array from one json variable

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

My question seems so simple to me that I cannot figure why I could not find an answer on the web. Really sorry in advance if this has been answered a thousand times, maybe I just don't have the wording right.

I am working with json formatted data in d3.js.

```
dataset = [
    {"category":"Fiction", "popularity":20},
    {"category":"Thriller", "popularity":45},
    {"category":"Romance", "popularity":12}
];
```

From all I know, some of the d3.js functions require a simple array.

**Example 1:** for a bar chart, my `d3.scale.ordinal().domain(data)` needs an array with ["Fiction", "Thriller", "Romance"]

**Example 2:** for a pie chart, the `d3.layout.pie(data)` function needs an array with [20,45,12]

These functions force me to extract all the values from "category" or "popularity" into one-dimensional array via simple `for loop`, which seems quite dumb.

Is there a more elegant and quick solution to extract an array with the values of one variable from a json?

Thanks a lot for your help!
Xavier

Comment: Well, you can hide the loop in a function…

Comment: That's not JSON, it's an object. You can use `.map()` to extract the values, but you'd need two `.map()` statements in a row to create both the `["Fiction","Thriller","Romance"]` and `[20,45,12]` arrays, so I would guess a simple `for` loop would be more efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
var category = dataset.map( function( obj ) { return obj.category; } );
var popularity = dataset.map( function( obj ) { return obj.popularity; } );
```

The category and popularity arrays will contain the values you need.

However, a for loop is likely to be a faster implementation.

Comment: Thanks a lot Bruno, I found the answer here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15783475/d3-js-define-ordinal-axis-from-json-data?rq=1) as well as soon as I was done posting :)

Comment: Surely a simple `for` loop would be more efficient than two `.map()` statements in a row? And it would end up with about the same amount of code to be typed... Using `.map()` is (arguably) "more elegant", but it doesn't win on "quick".

Comment: @nnnnnn You are correct a for loop is likely to be more efficient. However as xav was looking for an alternative to a for loop hence my suggestion. Nonetheless I think the idea to mention the performance implications is important. Thanks.

Comment: Well I gave you an upvote anyway, because like you said the OP was looking for a non-loop (or at least a non-explicit loop) solution. Just wanted to make sure performance got a mention too.